# Как привести список в Python к следующему виду?

Tags: python

Дана строка:

```
'''User1| 1234@mail.ru| qwerty
User2| 5678@mail.ru| asdfg
User3| 4321@mail.ru| abcdef'''
```

Как привести ее к следующему виду?

```
Имя: User1
Почта: 1234@mail.ru 
Пароль: qwerty
Имя: User2
Почта: 5678@mail.ru
Пароль: asdfg
Имя: User3
Почта: 4321@mail.ru
Пароль: abcdef
```

Comment: split()  поможет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В python есть метод, который разделяет строку 'str.split()'

Вот решение:

```
# Ваша строка с данными.
# Важно, чтобы каждая строка данных была на своей строке.
s = '''User1| 1234@mail.ru| qwerty
User2| 5678@mail.ru| asdfg
User3| 4321@mail.ru| abcdef'''

# В этот список будем складывать объекты с информацией
data = []
# s.splitlines() возвращает список строк данных, разбитый по символу переноса строки
# поэтому важно, чтобы инфо была на разных строчках
for line in s.splitlines():
  # метод split('|') разбивает строку на подстроки по символу |
  # Он возвращает tupple, поэтому мы можем присвоить 3м переменным значения, указав их через запятую
  name, mail, password = line.split('|')
  
  # добавляем в список объект с информацией, которую вытащили из строки
  data.append({'Имя': name, 'Почта': mail, 'Пароль': password})
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И вот так теперь с этими данными можно работать.

```
>>> data
[{'Имя': 'User1', 'Почта': ' 1234@mail.ru', 'Пароль': ' qwerty'}, {'Имя': 'User2', 'Почта': ' 5678@mail.ru', 'Пароль': ' asdfg'}, {'Имя': 'User3', 'Почта': ' 4321@mail.ru', 'Пароль': ' abcdef'}]
>>> data[0]
{'Имя': 'User1', 'Почта': ' 1234@mail.ru', 'Пароль': ' qwerty'}
>>> data[0]['Имя']
'User1'
>>> data[2]['Почта']
' 4321@mail.ru'
>>>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое и добра тебе

Comment: Пожалуйста большое и ДОБРА тебе!